# unexpected symbol in r spatial analysis

Tags: r, spatial

See code

```
p3 = Polygon(data.frame(x=c(438,414.3,383.5,374.6,357.6,368.4,395.5,471,516.2,636.8,671.1,651.1,564.1,525.2,438), y=c(343.5,366.1,429.6,454.3,507.7,563.2,594,627,644.7,577.1,502.4,417.9,375.7,358,343.5)))

p4 = Polygon(data.frame(x=c(464.2,444.3,428.9,421.6,464.3,539.1,580.9,586.1,574.8,530,464.2) + y=c(418.4,445.6,473,508.6,592.9,577.1,502.7,491.7,472.2,420.3,418.4)))
```

`p3` works but `p4` does not work

Error message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"p4 = Polygon(data.frame(x=c(464.2,444.3,428.9,421.6,464.3,539.1,580.9,586.1,574.8,530,464.2) y"
```

Comment: You don't have a comma before the `y` (as the error suggests)

Comment: @stefanie lsy I am guessing you copied multiple lines from the `R console` (which adds `+` sign before the beginning of each lines if the code is not complete) and then pasted it on the console.

Answer (score 2):

Remove plus sign and add comma:

```
Polygon(data.frame(
x=c(464.2,444.3,428.9,421.6,464.3,539.1,580.9,586.1,574.8,530,464.2),
y=c(418.4,445.6,473,508.6,592.9,577.1,502.7,491.7,472.2,420.3,418.4))
)
```

Mistakes are less common and debugging is easier if multiple steps are used:

```
x=c(464.2,444.3,428.9,421.6,464.3,539.1,580.9,586.1,574.8,530,464.2)
y=c(418.4,445.6,473,508.6,592.9,577.1,502.7,491.7,472.2,420.3,418.4)
dd = data.frame(x,y)
Polygon(dd)
```